# is there a datatype with thee different values like a boolean

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Is there a datatype in javaScript or PHP etc. that can contain just a view different custom values.
Like a boolean but with three types.
Like something like this: 
the value must be one of the following things "above", "under" or "in the middle".

Comment: Are you asking about enums?

Comment: Would [that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) work for you?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov but it is TypeScript the OP is asking about JS or PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution from this website: https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/08/21/enums-in-javascript/

```
const seasons = {
  SUMMER: {
    BEGINNING: "summer.beginning",
    ENDING: "summer.ending"
  },
  WINTER: "winter",
  SPRING: "spring",
  AUTUMN: "autumn"
};

let season = seasons.SUMMER.BEGINNING;

if (!season) {
  throw new Error("Season is not defined");
}

switch (season) {
  case seasons.SUMMER.BEGINNING:
  // Do something for summer beginning
  case seasons.SUMMER.ENDING:
  // Do something for summer ending
  case seasons.SUMMER:
  // This will work if season = seasons.SUMMER
  // Do something for summer (generic)
  case seasons.WINTER:
  //Do something for winter
  case seasons.SPRING:
  //Do something for spring
  case seasons.AUTUMN:
  //Do something for autumn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey in JavaScript there is no such thing, but you can use number and create some kind of enum like this

```js
const ENUM = {
  ABOVE: 1,
  MIDDLE: 0,
  UNDER: -1
}
```

and then use it like this:

```js
function acceptValue(en) {
  if (en === ENUM.ABOVE) {
    /* do something */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in PHP, but you could build your custom types like this:

```
class catLocation
{
    protected $val;
    protected $allowed = ['on', 'under'];

    public function __construct(string $val)
    {
        if(!in_array($val, $this->allowed)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('catLocation must be on or under');
        }
        $this->val = $val;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
         return $this->val;   
    }
}
```

... typehint it in your function definitions:

```
function whereIsCat(catLocation $loc) {
    return 'The cat is ' . $loc() . ' the table.'; 
    // Calling your object like a function will call the "magic" __invoke() method
}
```

... and use it like that:

```
$kitty_loc = new catLocation('under');

echo whereIsCat($kitty_loc); // The cat is under the table.
```